# SSRS: Diagram: Cumulate Values into new field

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, diagram, geometry

Hi there I'm currently using this Diagramm to Show percentages of Invoice Amount by Customers for my Company.
(Picture below filters out Values that are under 4%)

now since i have a lot of Customers that take less than 4%, i was hoping it could be possible to cumulate them all into a Collective Company called "Others"
I'm Using SQL Server Reporting Services 2012.

Does anybody know how this is done ?
Many thanks to you all.[image: Diagramm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find good details on this at [Collect Small Slices on a Pie Chart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207043.aspx).

Say we have a simple DataSet and a simple chart based on this:

[image]

[image]

Now, in the Designer, go to the chart **Chart Series** -> **CustomAttributes** and update:

- **CollectedStyle**
- **CollectedThreshold**
- **CollectedLegendText**

[image]

Now all your small slices are grouped together:

[image]

Obviously you may have to tweak slightly for your chart/data but this should give you a good start.